# Общие файлы Windows + Linux

Tags: linux, windows, файлы, файловая-система, dual-boot

На машине установлены две системы Windows + Linux. В основном используется Linux: для "повседневных задач" Blender 3D, Офис и т.д. Виндовс в основном для редактирования видео.

Нужно: сделать так, чтобы некоторые файлы (библиотеки текстур, видео и т.д.) были доступны в обеих системах.

Вижу два пути:

1. Подключить (установить) драйвера для ext* под Виндовс. Мне
   "завести" ext2fsd не удалось. При поиске нашёл то, что не
   рекомендуют устанавливать подобные драйвера на Виндовс, поскольку
   из-за их "кривизны" возможно подпортить ФС. Рекомендуют наоборот
   подключать НТФС тома в Виндовс.
2. Поддержка НТФС в линуксе есть "из коробки" и мудрить особо не
   надо, она достаточно неплохая. Но, есть тоже проблема. Если дело
   касается тома с библиотекам, то все в норме, но если нужно сделать
   доступной /home директорию (вернее поддиректорию "документы"), то
   как быть с правами на файлы, которые в НТФС отличаются от
   линуксовых? (Очень бы не хотелось держать домашнюю директорию в
   НТФС)

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким вопросом и как его решить?

Comment: А просто перенести поддиректорию "документы" на нтфс-раздел не?

Comment: NTFS — это максимально лучшее решение при данных обстоятельствах. У меня, кстати, внешний диск отформатирован именно в ntfs с такой целью, хотя я им в Windows года два уже не пользовался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу проблемы с данными на `nfts` разделе, там все имеют доступ. Но если у вас паранойя (как у меня например) то маунтите `ntfs` раздел в свою личную директорию, там можно любые права задать.

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня во всех файлах на НТФС разделе права 777

Comment: Права папки простые: R - чтение файлов, W - добавление новых файлов, X - прочитать листинг файлов. Создайте папку `секрет` с правами 700. Это значит что пользователь имеет полные права, группа и остальные не смогут даже войти в папку. Далее внутри этой секретной папки создайте пустую папку **ntfs** , на эту папку при включении моунтите ntfs диск. Только вы сможете зайти на ntfs раздел, так как папка `секрет` не пустит никого.